# Problems with adding a DVD drive

Tags: dvd

I have Ubuntu 12.04lts, it is a new machine, but I did not have an optical drive when I built it.  I just added a DVD drive today, and I'm trying to get things going but I'm running into problems.  In most of my searches (dealing with playing DVD movies) I noted that there should be a folder in /dev/dvd
I do not have such a folder, so I'm wondering if that is a problem and if so, how to fix it?

It seems when I search forums and even Askubuntu everyone just assumes this folder is there already.

Edit for further clarification:  The drive is recognized, but when a disk is inserted it appears in the /media folder instead of the dev/dvd folder.  I can search for files on the disk with mplayer and get it to play, but it doesn't just play if I choose it from the menu when the disk is inserted (mplayer or VLC).  I cannot get a movie to play at all with VLC player.  VLC gives me an error that reads "VLC could not read the file (input/output error).

According to my research so far, I have all of the proper codecs installed, and like I said I can force it to play in mplayer so I don't believe codecs are the issue.

Comment: the /dev folder is one that get repopulated on every boot, the kernel scans the available hardware devices(/dev) and then put a link or folder in the `/dev` folder, I would check that the DVD drive is plugged in firmly, or maybe try the 2nd plug(assuming you have a 2nd)

Comment: The drive actually works.  I even was able to get a movie to play.  That's part of my confusion.  The disk that's currently in the drive shows up in /media

Comment: umm, I guess I should have known that as your question implies it, if I had read it more carefully, is it possible that this is a blueray/dvd combo?  if so it might be seen as something else(blueray possibly, I'm not sure as I don't have one) to get a usable answer you should edit you question to say exactly what kinds of issues you are having and when they occur. include any error messages as well.

Comment: Its an LG DVD/rw drive no blu-ray.

Comment: I think /dev/sr0 is mostly used now instead of /dev/dvd i recall some programs may by default still look at /dev/dvd but can easily be configured to look at /dev/sr0

Comment: /dev/sr0 also does not exist.  Under /dev I have ati,block,bsg,bus,char,cpu,disk,fd,input,mapper,net,pts,shm,snd

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check in /cdrom folder which holds all type of optical media information rather than searching for /dev or /media..